# Recursive Table/Row Generator

Tags: java, arrays, recursion, matrix

I'm having a tough time wrapping my head around the following situation. The best way to explain may be by example

I have a Map<Column,Set<Row>> object.
Let's say it contains the following data:

```
ColumnA['abc','def']
ColumnB['efg','hij','klm']
ColumnC['nop']
ColumnD['qrs','tuv','wxy','zzz']
```

I am trying to generate the following output:

```
Row1[abc,efg,nop,qrs]
Row2[abc,efg,nop,tuv]
Row3[abc,efg,nop,wxy]
Row4[abc,efg,nop,zzz]
Row5[abc,hij,nop,qrs]
Row6[abc,hij,nop,wxy]
etc...
```

So in this case there would be 24 rows total.

However, the number of columns and rows are both dynamic.  I feel like this needs to be recursively done somehow but I'm not sure where to start.

Any help would be appreciated.

Update - I made a Tree structure that seems to work.

```
    DefaultMutableTreeNode root = new DefaultMutableTreeNode();
    Set<DefaultMutableTreeNode> curNodes = new HashSet<DefaultMutableTreeNode>();
    curNodes.add(root);

    final Set<Column> keys = map.keySet();
    for (final Column key : keys) {
        final Set<Row> rowSet = map.get(key);
        Set<DefaultMutableTreeNode> tmpNodes = new HashSet<DefaultMutableTreeNode>();
        for (final Row row : rowSet) {
            DefaultMutableTreeNode curNode = new DefaultMutableTreeNode();
            curNode.setUserObject(row);
            tmpNodes.add(curNode);
            for (DefaultMutableTreeNode n : curNodes) {
                n.add(curNode);
            }
        }
        curNodes = tmpNodes;
    }
```

Comment: Maybe it makes more sense to create a tree from this structure where each column would represent a tree level?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I hope this is not some student's homework.

First to keep the order of the map's keys the same, use a [`SortedMap`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/SortedMap.html), like `TreeMap`.
Furthermore in your initial map every Row contains just a single value like 'abc'.
Recursion here is a depth-first traversal. The hard thing is that a map has not a
natural traversal. For the rest have todos/candidates and dones/result; do a step changing data and afterwards restore them.

*Here I use the more known List, but a Stack would be nicer.*

```
public List<Row> generateRows(SortedMap<Column, Set<Cell>> map) {
    List<Row> done = new ArrayList<Row>();
    List<Column> columnsToDo = new LinkedList<Column>(map.keySet());
    List<Cell> partialRow = new LinkedList<Cell>();
    generateRowsRec(map, columnsToDo, partialRow, done);
    return done;
}
void generateRowsRec(SortedMap<Column, Set<Cell>> map, List<Column> columnsToDo, List<Cell> partialRow, List<Row> done) {
    if (columnsToDo.isEmpty()) {
        done.add(new Row(partialRow));
        return;
    }
    Column firstColumn = columnsToDo.remove(0); // Step A
    for (Cell cell : map.get(firstColumn)) {
        partialRow.add(cell); // Step B
        generateRowsRec(map, columnsToDo, partialRow, done);
        partialRow.remove(partialRow.size() - 1); // Unstep B
    }
    columnsToDo.add(0, firstColumn); // Unstep A
}
```

Comment: No, this isn't a homework assignment.  I've built a Tree which seems to put everything in the correct order. I'll post what I have so far. However, I'd like to try this out as well and see how it goes. I'm curious about how both would perform under high load (lots of values). I'd definitely like to thank you for the insight and sample.